# Filter a list based on a selection

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given the data below, I have two select lists, the first select list is to display the name of each person... the second select list is two display the name of the children of the selected person. Using lodash what is the easiest way to do this?

```
const people = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "bob",
    gender: "male",
    children: [{
      id: "1",
      name: "sarah"
    }]

  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "tom",
    gender: "male",
    children: [{
      id: "1",
      name: "lisa"
    }]

  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "sue",
    gender: "female",
    children: [{
      id: "1",
      name: "larry"
    }]

  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the solution as below:

```
import map from "lodash/map";
import partialRight from "lodash/partialRight";
import pick from "lodash/pick";
import find from "lodash/find";

const test = [
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "tom",
    gender: "male",
    children: [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "lisa"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "sue",
    gender: "female",
    children: [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "larry"
      }
    ]
  }
];

// Person selection list
const persons = map(test, partialRight(pick, ["id", "name", "gender"]));
// Replace selected person value in `persons[0]`.
const childrens = find(test, item => item.id === persons[0].id).children;
```